# Failed to upgrade *.nib-file because it has a dependency on an Interface Builder 3 plug-in

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5, nib

I recently upgraded my XCode from 3.2.2 to 4.5.2.
An old project compiles fine but I can't change two of its three *.nib-files.

When trying to open it XCode tells me that the document has a dependency on an Interface Builder 3 plug-in and that I should click on upgrade.

When I click on "Upgrade" XCode returns that the upgrade failed due to the dependency on an Interface Builder 3 plug-in which is very misleading.

Screenshots of the message boxes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use "ibtool MainMenu.nib --upgrade --write MainMenu.xib" to convert the .nib to a .xib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [What's New In Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_1.html):

**Interface Builder Plug-in Support**

> If you used Interface Builder plug-ins in Xcode 3, you can continue to
>   build and run your project in Xcode 4, and you can update your project
>   to make your nib files editable in Xcode 4.
>
> Xcode 4 provides limited support for Interface Builder 3 plug-ins.
>   Specifically, you can build a project with Interface Builder plug-in
>   dependencies, but you can’t edit the nib files. When you try to open a
>   nib file with plug-in dependencies, Xcode 4 displays a dialog
>   suggesting that you update the file. If you agree, Xcode converts the
>   class of custom objects built with plug-ins to the nearest AppKit
>   class. If the conversion isn’t possible, Xcode 4 provides a detailed
>   error message. In that case, **you must remove the plug-in dependency
>   using Interface Builder 3 before you can edit the nib file in Xcode 4**.

Comment: Can I get Interface Builder 3 anywhere without downloading the whole XCode 3 ?

Comment: @Hedge I don't think so, no.

Comment: What do these plugins actually do?

Comment: Solution 1) use VirtualBox, get every version of Mac OS X for the past 10 years and all the Xcodes.

Comment: Solution 2) plutil -convert xml1 A.nib; replace the class with NSView; plutil -convert binary1 A.nib; open in Xcode to see warnings if another class is needed to chang.